# "XAMLTaskFactory" could not be loaded from Assembly

Tags: visual-studio, .net-assembly

I've been trying to run x86 assembly code on my machine for schoolwork. Sadly I've been getting this error when trying to build the project files and I can't figure out what it's about and how to fix it:

```
Error   MSB4175 The task factory "XamlTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". The system cannot find the path specified hi  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets  70
```

Has anyone had the same problem? I've tried making new projects, running as administrator, done a clean install of Visual Studio and all the packages, even factory reset my laptop.

Comment: @TomV We have a [.net-assembly] tag for questions about that meaning of assembly, as in the error message.  Although IDK if it's actually appropriate to tag it in questions that aren't about *creating* one, just an error message about finding one.  Still, sounds like it should be tagged [visual-studio].  Unclear on [assembly]; the question actually does say they want to run "x86 assembly code", but unclear whether they mean assembly language like `mov ax, 123`, or code in a .NET-assembly.